# Rails turbolinks JS files Bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

All my .js files look like this:

```
function function_name(){
.....
some code
.....
}
$(document).ready(function_name);
$(document).on('page:load', function_name);
```

I use `setInterval(some_function, 7000)`, Event handlers like `$(document).on('click', '.blah-blah', function(){...})`. Unfortunately, these stuff calls multiple times if I a have more than one request to server via turbolinks (using turbolinks session). Actually amount of calls equals to the amount of server requests. 
For instance, I have `<button id="button"></button>` and js event handler, handler executes as many times as requests in turbolinks session I have. It's so annoying)

I'd like you to find out how to keep turbolinks turned on and avoid multiple calls inside js files. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

1. In the code that does things like sets the interval or adds a handler, check first to see if the interval or handler already exists, and don't add another one if there's already one there.
2. Attach to [one of the other events from turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks#events) like `"page:before-change"` or `"page:before-unload"` and remove the interval or handler in there.

Comment: Can you explain why it happens? Why it executes multiple times?

Comment: Without looking specifically at your code, let me give you the overview answer: Turbolinks leaves the page itself loaded in memory, it basically turns all regular links into ajax style calls, so Rails sends back only the body of the new page, and the turbolinks JS loads that body into the existing page. That means that all your JS stays in memory, so if you had an interval running, it stays running. Then your `page:load` function adds another interval, and then they'll both fire.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is what I wanted to hear)